# Why are rocket engines shaped like a bell rather than a gun barrel?

Tags: spacecraft, engines, engine-design, thrust

When blasting matter out of a spacecraft engine for thrust, it seems like you'd want as much velocity in one direction as possible. Why do spacecraft engines (e.g., Apollo CSM) have big bell-shaped covers on them, rather than a long gun-like barrel to help direct all the exhaust?

Comment: This is a good question, but it has good answers already. In short, expanding the exhaust reduces the transverse velocity of the molecules (by cooling the gas) and making the motion more parallel.

Comment: There's more to it than that, @uhoh. The flare in a de Laval thruster increases the exhaust velocity and thereby increases thrust. This increase in velocity as the gas moves further toward the exit goes hand in hand with a decrease in the local temperature and pressure of the gas.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'm not sure if that's more than reducing transverse velocity, or a different and perhaps more specific way to describe the same thing. I see the nozzle as converting a roughly isotropic distribution of velocity vectors of the molecules into a more anisotropic distribution. Ignoring post-combustion chemical reactions, we have to conserve $\Sigma v^2$ of all the molecules, so the nozzle simply makes them all move in more of the same direction. That can be called "cooling".

Comment: @DavidHammen [Balloon of ideal gas pops in vacuo - K.E. per atom unchanged, velocities become locally correlated?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249582/83380) I've accepted my own temporary answer but a better one would be most welcomed!

Comment: @uhoh There's a lot more to it than that. A converging-diverging nozzle wouldn't make sense if the flow was subsonic throughout. With a purely subsonic flow you would want a  purely converging nozzle. It's the weird and counterintuitive behaviors of supersonic flow that makes the supersonic gas accelerate after the throat of a nozzle. The flow is subsonic before the throat, Mach 1 at the throat, and supersonic after the throat.

Comment: @DavidHammen okay thanks, I'll put it in the queue of things I hope to understand some day :-)